# printing to 1980s Olympia typewriter/daisywheel printer from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer

I'm trying to print to an old 1980s-era Olympia Compact S Typewriter/Daisy Wheel Printer from Windows 7. This is basically a typewriter/printer that was manufactured around 1986. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I can connect to my PC using a USB-to-parallel (Centronics) cable. Windows 7 recognizes the IEEE 1284 controller (Centronics parallel interface), but *not* as a printer. Historically, it seemed to operate with a “generic” daisy wheel interface; this was probably Windows 95!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there are no available drivers for such a device. That leaves you a few choices:

Write one yourself. This is likely to be a very involved task, as most modern printers are more of the bitmap or vector variety, and can do all sorts of tricks. A driver for such an old beast is going to have to make up for all that and map everything down to the actual capabilities of this printer.

Write a program to just talk to this printer. I'm guessing that since windows sees the adapter, you could probably open the port more or less like a COM port and write bytes to it. Now you're back to the good-old-days of spitting bytes at the printer. The downside here is that of course you have no applications (except your own) that can use the thing. Given that it can only print text plus a few effects anyway, this might not be that big of a deal, and could be an interesting project.

Put the appropriate ASCII bytes into a text file and dump it to the appropriate port using cmd.exe. Something like

```
type myfile.txt > LPT1
```

Might work, assuming that Windows mapped your adapter to LPT1. This is at least less of a project than writting a program to do the job, and you can easily create text files using any text editor. For fancy effects, it might be helpful to get an editor like Notepad++ where you can easily show invisible characters. You'll also want to hunt around for the printer's manual so you know what code set it uses.

Comment: This is likely to be the "only" answer, what `LPT1` is in practice probably depends entirely on the USB-thing. As you have the port name it should be just as simple as shown above, just replacing `LPT1` . Any available `commands` (escape-sequences) might allow to set tab stops and similar, possibly stopping for daisy-wheel change, maybe beeping for ascii BEL (code 7)... and some such.

Comment: If you can't find the manual, then trying with what is in e.g. https://www.star-m.jp/eng/service/usermanual/lc2420um.pdf may turn out to work for some things.

Comment: A better way is to use the Generic/Text Only driver. That even lets you add a few printer-specific commands (via Printer Properties > Commands tab)

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old. But the answer is more simple than you think. Just use the Windows generic text printer driver and it should work.

In Linux you can plug in the cable and try this command and it should send the text to the printer as is:

```
cat examplefile.txt > /dev/usb/lp0
```

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you mean by your first paragraph? E.g., how is it different from `type myfile.txt > LPT1`, which was given as an answer six months ago?

Comment: @G-Man It's different in that Windows lets you add "generic text printer driver" as a proper "printer" that you can print to using the usual visual interface you're familiar with, rather than requiring using the command line.

Comment: I just got a Royal LetterMaster (from the 1980s), and after a bit of fiddling about, I can confirm that Generic / Text Only Printer works fine with a USB-to-Parallel cable for this daisy wheel printer. And this is on Windows 8.1 x64!